# How can I implement an async thrift server?

Tags: c#, async-await, thrift

I generate an async c# class with below command on thrift.

```
thrift-0.12.0.exe --gen csharp:async file.thrift
```

and then I implement all defined methods in async type in c#.
Now my question is: How can i run a thrift server in c# that work in async type? 
Below example from thrift repository on GitHub is sync. I need its async version. Please somebody help me.

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
            try
            {
                CalculatorHandler handler = new CalculatorHandler();
                Calculator.Processor processor = new Calculator.Processor(handler);
                TServerTransport serverTransport = new TServerSocket(9090);
                TServer server = new TSimpleServer(processor, serverTransport);

                // Use this for a multithreaded server
                // server = new TThreadPoolServer(processor, serverTransport);

                Console.WriteLine("Starting the server...");
                server.Serve();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.StackTrace);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("done.");
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by async? Do you want to start the server in the background and do other work in parallel? If so, put it into its own thread.

Comment: I want just use all of thread for response to clients. maximum responsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there.

```
thrift-0.12.0.exe --gen csharp:async file.thrift
```

This will generate two interfaces per service: The "traditional" synchronous `IFace` and an asynchronous variant named `IAsync` which is what you need to implement.

Furthermore, instead of using the `YourService.Processor` implementation you want to use `YourService.AsyncProcessor`.

The new netstd implementation of 0.13.0 (which will obsolete C# and netcore bindings in future releases) **only** supports the async variant.

### Example

Example.thrift

```
namespace * Example

service Example {
    double Ping(1: double input)
}
```

generates Example.cs

```
namespace Example
{
    public interface IAsync {
      Task<double> PingAsync(double input);
    }

    // more code ...
}
```

ExampleHandler.cs implements your service

```
namespace ExampleSvc
{
    public class HandlerImpl : Example.Example.IAsync  
    {
        public Task<double> PingAsync(double input, CancellationToken cancel)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(input);
        }
    }
}
```

ServerMain.cs sets the server up

```
// create protocol factory, we use framed compact
var protoFactory = new TCompactProtocol.Factory();
var transFactory = new TFramedTransport.Factory();
var handler = new ExampleSvc.HandlerImpl();
var processor = new Example.Example.AsyncProcessor(handler);

var servertrans = new TServerSocketTransport(9000);
var serverEngine = new TThreadPoolAsyncServer(processor, servertrans, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
serverEngine.ServeAsync(CancellationToken.None).Wait();
```

Especially the latter one is assembled from a much larger netstd source file and simplified down to server as an example. I did not test this Example, but that's about how it should look.

Comment: I do your recommend. I don't know how to use ``MyService.AsyncProcessor``  to implement server. how to use ``MyService.AsyncProcessor`` object for write server code.

Comment: I'll put together an example, stay tuned.

Comment: in `ServerMain.cs` file at line `var serverEngine = new TThreadPoolAsyncServer(processor, servertrans, transportFactory, protocolFactory);
`  the `processor` object have an error.

Comment: "have an error" is a poor problem description. I usually answer that with "it works for me".